# How to add Google Analytics to reStructuredText?

Tags: python, restructuredtext, docutils

I am using reStructured text to create some easy websites. 
So I have got a lot of *.rst files in which I want to add the Google Analytics code.
But as far as I know it is not possible to add something like this?!

I am using rst2html to convert the files to html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just discovered an easy way to add custom content to .rst files. All you need to do it to modify the template for html files.

Make a new template template.txt and the following contents to it (based on the default template):

```
%(head_prefix)s
%(head)s
<!--your tracking code-->
%(stylesheet)s
%(body_prefix)s
%(body_pre_docinfo)s
%(docinfo)s
%(body)s
%(body_suffix)s
```

The format is pretty self explanatory and its also a good way to remove the default CSS and specify a link to another one in the template etc.

Now you can use your custom template with the rst2html writer:

```
rst2html.py --template=template.txt document.rst
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you'd have to extend the docutils HTML Translator or Writer to include GA.

If possible, I'd recommend to abandon rst2html and plain docutils and use [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) instead.  It is based on docutils, but far more powerful.  Its HTML templates can easily be extended to include arbitrary HTML like script tags for Google Analytics.

Comment: I will have a look at Sphinx. Thank you.

Comment: Sphinxis great for manuals, but for a website you might prefer rest2web http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/rest2web/

Answer (score 2):

You can insert html to rst files using the [.. raw:: directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through).

Comment: Unfortunately I need to add the HTML to the header. As far as I see this is not possible with the raw:: directive?!

Comment: In case of GA you don't need to add the code to the header, but right before the </body> tag, which means you place at the end of your .rst document.

Comment: Google said: 
Copy the following code, then paste it onto every page you want to track immediately before the closing head tag.

But I also found this:
http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55488

I guess to add it to the header is better...

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround to your problem, you could use a mass search/replace tool to add the Google Analytics code to the files *after* they have been through the translator. Just search for the `</body>` tag and replace it with `<!--your tracking code--></body>`.

I checked to see if you can include raw HTML in reStructuredText (and have it be untouched), but it doesn't seem possible...

Comment: actually, you can add an invisible text in RST with `.. comment` syntax, it will be converted to comment on conversion to HTML

Comment: I don't think you can include HTML markup... that's a comment.

Comment: Good idea! Thanks. But I need something more comprehensive.